# Does a .Net standard Xamarin.Forms application have the Dependencies, NuGet and SDK folder in the Android and iOS projects?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a bit confused about implementing the .Net standard application which has a iOS and Android project.

Can someone tell me does a .Net standard Xamarin.Forms application have the Dependencies, NuGet and SDK folder in the Android and iOS projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone tell me does a .Net standard Xamarin.Forms application
>   have the Dependencies, NuGet and SDK folder in the Android and iOS
>   projects?

Platform targeting projects cannot be a `.NET Standard` projects, therefore there are minor differences in the structure.

- `Dependencies` -> `References` - Can be a reference to another project or assembly. Defined in the `csproj` and depends on your setup should be in the solution.
- `NuGet` -> `Packages` - defined in the `csproj` and depends on the setup may live under `packages` directory within the solution or in a `NuGet` cache.
- `SDK` directory is missing. It is set under project options in the `Target framework`.

Comment: So the answer to my question is "no"?

Comment: Not exactly. As mentioned above Android and iOS projects still have “dependencies” under slightly different names: x -> y